# Unable to open UPI apps from Android and IOS in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, url, flutter-layout, upi

[image]

I am trying to add this URL launcher. But I am getting **component name for upi://pay?pa=dinesh@dlanzer&pn=Dinesh&am=1&tn=hello&cu=INR is null** error. For SMS and E-Mail works fine.

Comment: Can you test the link

Answer (score 0):

first you have to used URL launcher plug in in flutter

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.

  # url launcher
  url_launcher: ^6.1.4
```

now i make UPI Launcher helper function
where i can launch my upi in multiple app  like paytm,phonePay,Gpay,BHIM,WhatsappPay etc.

here i pass
upiID, (Required)
Name (Optional)
Amount (Optional)
Note (Optional)

you can still pass more data as per required

show helperFunction

```
paymentUrlLaunch({
  required String upi,
  String? amount,
  String? name,
  String? note,
}) async {
  String nameUrl = (name != null && name.isNotEmpty) ? "&pn=$name" : "";
  String amountUrl = (amount != null && amount.isNotEmpty) ? "&am=$amount" : "";
  String noteUrl = (note != null && note.isNotEmpty) ? "&tn=$note" : "";
  String link = 'upi://pay?pa=$upi' +
      nameUrl +
      amountUrl +
      noteUrl +
      "&cu=INR" ;

  Uri url = Uri.parse(link);

  var willLaunch = await canLaunchUrl(url);  // from url launcher plugIN
  if (willLaunch) {
    launchUrl(url);
  } else {
    upiToaster(msg: 'Url not launch'); // if failed notified by toaster
  }

 
}
```

please note
here passed UPIID, Name, Amount and Note using TextFormField and controller with validation

hope this will help you